# Ajax live page load after delete (ajax, codeigniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hello I have problem here..

I am going to delete record using Ajax and codeigniter..
but when the record in database deleted , the view doesn't change..
I think it needs a live page load but don't know how..

Here is my view..

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary"  href="#" onclick="deleteFav('<?php echo $favbook[$x]['Bibli'];      ?>')">Delete
      </a>

    <script>
function deleteFav(bibli)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type    :"POST",
            url     : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>favorite_book/deleteFav",
            async   : false,
            data    : {
                        Bibli:bibli
                      },
            success : function(data){

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Here is my model

```
    function addfav($Bibli, $createTime, $username)
    {

        $data_fav = array(
            'Bibli' => $Bibli,
            'FavoriteDate' => $createTime,
            'Username' => $username,
            'CreatedTime' => $createTime,
            'AuditActivity' => 'I'
        );
        echo $this->db->insert('msfavoriteasset',$data_fav);

    }
```

My controller

```
public function deleteFav()
{
    $data = $this->input->post();

    print_r($this->input->post('Bibli'));
    $createTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('+6 hours'));        
    $success = $this->favoritebook_model->delete($data["Bibli"], $this->session->userdata('username'));

}
```

Comment: your ajax success is empty. what are you trying to do there?

Comment: I'm going just delete the row in my views..

Comment: after delete redirect to the controller for display the list

Comment: then you have to update the view after ajax success

Comment: Or better refresh the page in success.

Comment: In ajax success, kindly delete the anchor link
<a class="btn btn-primary"  href="#" onclick="deleteFav('<?php echo $favbook[$x]['Bibli'];      ?>')">Delete
      </a>

Comment: @kumar_v yes but I don't know how..:(

Comment: @DurgaprasadBudhwani whoa thanks..but why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"  href="#"  data-bibli="<?php echo $favbook[$x]['Bibli'];      ?>">Delete</a>

<script>
    function deleteFav(bibli, this)
        {
            $.ajax({
                type    :"POST",
                url     : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>favorite_book/deleteFav",
                async   : false,
                data    : {
                            Bibli:bibli
                          },
                success : function(data){
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
        }

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".btn-primary").click(function(){
           var bibli = $(this).data("bibli");
           deleteFav(bibli, this);
       });
    });
</script>
```

Don't forget to add this parameter on `onclick="deleteFav('<?php echo $favbook[$x]['Bibli'];      ?>', this)`

Comment: `this` is undefined here

Comment: <a class="btn btn-primary"  href="#" onclick="deleteFav('<?php echo $favbook[$x]['Bibli'];      ?>', this)">Delete
      </a>

Comment: Have modified the above code, can you please test with that.
Please note that, on click event is removed from anchor and data attribute is added in anchor  tag

Answer (score 0):

try this code as per discussion in comment.

```
success : function(data){
                var delay=2000//2 seconds
                setTimeout(function(){

                   //your code to be executed after 2 seconds
                    location.reload();
                },delay)

            }
```

Comment: Is this comment for me?

Comment: eh no sorry its for durgaprasad

Comment: why need to give some time?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that what you needs is that when a user clicks delete, a person has to be removed from his fav list and you need to update the view of person being removed from the list.

This is done in the following manner you could delete the person and send the new list as Ajax reply after deleting and update the list.

ie   `success : function(data){ $('#favlist_div').html(data); }`

This replaces the original list with updated list.

Or you could simply remove the person from the list as following

I suppose you are listing the favourite person with an image and a remove button
If echo $favbook[$x]['Bibli'] is a unique id

```
<div id="div_<?php echo $favbook[$x]['Bibli']; ?>">
<img .....>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" onclick="deleteFav('<?php echo $favbook[$x]['Bibli'];?>')"> Delete </a>
</div>
```

then in the the success you could simply remove the div as

```
success : function(data){ $('#div_'+bibli).hide(); }
```